# What is the cost of returning to Barovia? (Adventure League Season 4, (04-14) Curse of Strahd)

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development, dnd-adventurers-league

After getting out of Barovia in *Dark Lord*, what is the cost of going back to Barovia, in terms of GP or downtime, if there is one?

This is for D&D Adventurer's League 4-14.

After I finish the EPIC reclamation of phlan, I want to go back to Barovia to finish hardcover CoS

Answer (score 2):

You can return to Barovia by playing a scenario that gives you the Demiplane of Dread story award again.  [The Adventurer's League FAQ says:](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/DDADVL_FAQv3.pdf)

> *Does Curse of Strahd Award the Demiplane of
>   Dread Story Award?*
>
> As implied in the Death in Ravenloft sidebar (ALDMG
>   p8), characters who play one (or more) sessions of
>   Curse of Strahd or DDLE4 Death House are trapped in
>   Barovia.
>
> While not explicitly stated in the sidebar, such
>   characters are assumed to have gained the story
>   award upon entering the Demiplane of Dread. For
>   your convenience, the story award is as follows:
>
> **Demiplane of Dread (Story Award)**
>
> You have traversed the mists and now find yourself in the
>   Demiplane of Dread and, until this story award is removed,
>   you are unable to leave. So long as you are trapped, you
>   cannot participate in any adventure or event that takes place
>   outside of Barovia. Tread carefully during your time here, the
>   Dark Powers are watching.

Note the "or more," which I would interpret as saying once you get Demiplane of Dread lifted by returning, you can get it again in the normal way.

Keep in mind it'll get harder to get out - per [this Adventurer's League announcement](http://dndadventurersleague.org/barexit-escaping-the-mists-of-barovia/), if you try to leave just by using Downtime,

> +10 Downtime Days – Escape the Mists – Each time a character escapes the mists, but then returns to Barovia, escaping again gets progressively harder.

Which also clearly implies you can return. You'll need to play another of the adventures that lets you escape or have sufficient Downtime to get back out again.

There's no affordance for just using Downtime or other costs to get into Barovia, you need to play in another scenario that puts you there.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways I can see you getting back, but I'm unsure of how well they would fit in with Adventurer's League or if they would even be allowed.

***Method 1: Attempt to plane shift***

According to the DMG (pg. 68), a spellcaster could attempt to get to Barovia (or any other Demiplane) by casting Plane Shift with a tuning fork attuned to Barovia's frequency. The fork itself has a base cost of 250gp (PHB 266) but it may cost more to find one (or craft one) that has been attuned to Barovia.

Alternatively, it may be easier to find a fork attuned to the Shadowfell and attempt to find Barovia and the Domains of Dread. The DMG (pg 51) mentions that the Domains of Dread are a Demiplane in the Shadowfell which may make getting back somewhat easier.

***Method 2: Find some Vistani***

Some Vistani people roam other planes and may be willing to escort adventurers to their home land in the Land of Mists.

***Method 3: Perform an evil act***

The Domains of Dread sort of act as a prison for evil doers. Strahd, for example,

> was trapped here after he made a pact to become a vampire and murdered his younger brother in order to have a second shot at wooing his love, Tatyana.

The mists of the Domains of Dread drew his realm (Barovia) in and now he is cursed to constantly fall for women who will be fated to die before they could marry. Smaller evil acts could see a player drawn back into the mist.

Comment: I have to -1; Adventurer's League is organized play and there will only be defined paths to get there, you can't treat it like a home game where you just get your DM to make something up.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations that prevent you from immediately playing a ravenloft adventure. You just get stuck again if you do.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG.SE. Check out our [tour] to familiarise yourself with how we work around here. The question seems to be seeking in-game means of actually travelling there deliberately; naturally one can just go "boom, you're there again, adventure says so" and that's a fair point, but I suggest you be aware that in-game costs and means might be what the question's going for.